# Как подключить Wysimark на Plain JS?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

Есть [Wysimark](https://www.wysimark.com/docs/js) - WYSIWYG Markdown Editor

Устанавливал через `pnpm add @wysimark/standalone`

В [доках](https://www.wysimark.com/docs/js) почему-то не написано как подключать с помощью указания тэга `script`, хотя написано что решение `Plain JS` (или это что-то другое?)
Подклчаю так

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="editor-container"></div>
        <script defer type=module src='index.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`index.js`

```
import { createWysimark } from "@wysimark/standalone"

const container = document.getElementById("editor-container")

const wysimark = createWysimark(container, {
  initialMarkdown: "# Hello World",
})
```

Выдаёт ошибку

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/cmwysiwig/node_modules/@wysimark/standalone/.dist/browser/index.cjs.js' does not provide an export named 'createWysimark' (at index.js:1:10)`

ЧЯДНТ?